# How can I scale something while centering it using justify-content: center?

Tags: html, css

I have a div element that I want to center in the middle of the page, but when I add `transform: scale(3)`, it's not centered anymore. The div is 112px in width and height and I dont want to use `position` nor `left/right/top/bottom`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.scale {
  transform: scale(3);
}
div {
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="scale"></div>
</body>
```

How can I center the div while scaling it up?

Answer (score 1):

Transforming an element makes no difference to the amount of space it occupies. It is centered in the sense the height of the body has not changed.

If you experiment with say giving the body a height that isn't just dependent on the height of that element then you will see that the element remains centered more clearly. (Run the snippet in full page)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.scale {
  transform: scale(3);
}
div {
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="scale"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the transform point to the center. try add the css below to the scale element.

```
.scale{
   transform-origin: center;
}
```

Comment: Isn't center the default value for transform-origin? I can't see that adding this to the given snippet makes any difference.

Comment: default is top left

Comment: Isn't that for SVG - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin "Note: The default value of transform-origin is 0 0 for all SVG elements except for root <svg> elements and <svg> elements that are a direct child of a foreignObject, and whose transform-origin is 50% 50%, like other CSS elements."